# When integrated Karate with CICD Jenkins job - which report is suitable to publish in the section Editable Email notifications to publish mailble rep

Tags: jenkins, report, karate

In cucumber serenity , we have something called Serenity Summary report that has proper structure like below in email notification after each Jenkins job run [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpJNb.png)

Same way , do we have any summary report to be attached through mails , because when i attach overview-features.html , the graphical elements are eliminated and the report looks like below in the mail  , is there any more formatted one that can be used?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHWk8.png)

In Jenkins settings is as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L76aI.png)